# Required fields one of two fields

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am writing in asp.net c#.

I want a control similiar to RequiredFieldValidator except I want one of two fields to be required. I found an excellent example for two text fields but in my case one field is a check box and the other is an text box. If the check box is not checked the text box must be entered.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use javascript or C# code to check this.
I personally don't care for the RequiredFieldValidator types as they are limited and rather confusing.

With C# server side code you could just check

`if (!chk.Checked && txtBox.Text.Length==0)`

For JavaScript something to this effect:

```
if (!(document.getElementById('myCheckBox').Checked) 
     && document.getElementByID('myTextBox').val=='')
```

Comment: I think I'll take your advise and use c# code. The RequiredFieldValidator is not buying me anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the customvalidator if you have complex custom validation logic. This is probably your best way to go.